# Custom Deserialization in WCF Rest

Tags: wcf, rest, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I'm writing a WCF REST service and trying to use the ideas in Carlos Figueira's blog post [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a) to customize my deserialization.

There's just one problem. I'd like my custom `IDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest()` to both:

1. Deserialize the request body
2. And parse the URI into method parameters (just as WCF by default does).

For example, if I have the below method in my service contract:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/{uriPart1}/{uriPart2}")]
void Func(string uriPart1, string uriPart2, SomeObject messageBodyObject);
```

then my `DeserializeRequest()` implementation should not only deserialize the POST message body into `messageBodyObject`, it should also assign the correct values from the URI to `uriPart1`, `uriPart2` parameters.

Carlos's code does not do the second part.

I'd like to know how I can achieve this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not take a look at the Web API project (http://wcf.codeplex.com)?  It uses WCF under the covers and it does what you are describing.